# In D&D 4e, can you use Dual Weapon Attack on a Charge?

Tags: dnd-4e, charge

I'm a fairly new DM for 4e (1.5 years). I have a player playing a Scout that has a Dual Weapon Attack At-Will. Can he use this on a Charge? In Character Builder, it seems as though the trigger of "hitting with a melee basic attack" is fulfilled, but I've also seen forums where it indicates only ONE attack can EVER be made on a charge. Unfortunately, I don't know if this is a 3.5 or 4e rule.

Can anyone help me out...especially if they know where the rule is listed in the PH/PH2/etc.?

Answer (score 7):

You can in fact use Dual Weapon Attack on a charge. Here is the trigger and action type for [Dual Weapon attack](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=13619):

> Free Action      Melee weapon
>
> Trigger: You hit with a melee basic attack on your turn.

Here is the relevant text of [Charge](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=324):

> No Further Actions: The creature can’t take any further actions during this turn, **except free actions**. A creature’s turn usually ends after it charges. However, it can extend its turn by taking certain free actions. (PHB 287, RC 240, emphasis mine)

Since the attack on a charge is a Melee basic attack, and you can still take free actions after a charge, you can absolutely use Dual Weapon Attack (you can also use an AP to attack again if you wanted to).

Comment: Using the AP is a free action, but the action it gives you isn't, so by my reading the AP would be wasted, because you couldn't use the action it gave you.

Comment: @DCShannon no, action points are allowed after charges, and it gives you another action. That free action specifier is there specifically to allow you to extend your turn (see "it can *extend* its turn by taking certain free actions" (by which it means an action point, or something else)